# Регулярные выражения, буквы

Tags: c#, регулярные-выражения

Необходимо искать слово из **трех букв(3), первая(1) и последняя(3) - *гласные*.**

```
string[] words = line.Split(' ');
char[] letters = new char[] { 'а', 'о', 'у', 'э', 'ы', 'я', 'ё', 'ю', 'е', 'и', 'в' };
bool firstIsVowel, lastIsVowel;
foreach (var word in words)
{
      foreach (var letter in letters)
      {
             firstIsVowel = (new Regex($"^{letter}" + @"\w{2}").IsMatch(word));
             lastIsVowel = (new Regex(@"^\w{2}" + $"{letter}").IsMatch(word));
             if (firstIsVowel && lastIsVowel)
                            tbTask2.Text += word;
      }
 }
```

Я получил предложение line, успешно разбил на слова words, проверяю первую и последнюю букву - гласная ли она, имею два флага, которые дают знать - обе бувквы гласные, или нет... но ничего не получается, где я прокололся?

Comment: `'в'` не гласная буква. `if (Regex.IsMatch(word, @"^[аоуэыяёюе]\p{L}[аоуэыяёюе]$")) {/* Хорошее слово */}`. Ну, или что-то в этом духе подойдёт (вместо `\p{L}`, `[а-яА-ЯёЁ]`).

Comment: А зачем вы так странно в цикле по очереди перебираете буквы. сделайте единую регулярку типа: `[аоуеи]\w[аоуеи]` (список букв конечно надо расширить)

Comment: замечу, что если нет строго формата входной строки, то слова могут разделяться также табуляциями и символами новой строки

Comment: `new RegEx()` из цикла следует вынести. да и в целом для такого конкретного условия проверки двух символов будет более эффективным без использования регулярных выражений.

Comment: string[] words = line.Split(' ');
                    foreach (var word in words)
                        if (Regex.IsMatch(word, @"^[аоуэыяёюе][а-яА-ЯёЁ][аоуэыяёюе]$"))
                            tbTask2.Text += word;

Comment: Я помню чудное 10-е мгновенье:
Инь Янь жил подо мной,
Передо мной явилась 200 ворон,
Как мимолетное виденье,
Как гений чистой ухи,

инь, янь, ухи - не зацепило

Comment: @Kryshtop а зачем вообще регулярные выражения то здесь?

Comment: учим потихоньку.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Спасибо @VladD за помощь с С#.

```
var re = new Regex(@"\b[аеоиуюэяёы][а-яё][аеоиуюэяёы]\b",
                       RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Compiled);
var result = re.Matches(text)
```

В массиве `result` будут содержаться все совпадения, как объекты `Match`.

Живой пример:

http://ideone.com/RJhfrL

Comment: С Юникодом должно работать нормально. Вот вам playground, если хотите: http://ideone.com/43cgru.

Comment: @VladD http://ideone.com/RJhfrL как-то так лучше наверно.

Comment: Ага, или так. Я имел в виду, чтобы можно было протестировать несколько строк за один пробег. Ваш вариант более идиоматично так: http://ideone.com/5B5yjT

Comment: Можно ещё добавить `| RegexOptions.Multiline`, чтобы `^$` означали начало/конец каждой строки в тексте. (Но в нашем варианте это не нужно.)

Comment: Спасибо, исправил ответ.

Comment: Всегда пожалуйста!

Answer (score 0):

мой вариант ответа не подходит под условия автора относительно использования регулярных выражений, но пусть останется как альтернативный, особенно с условием того что не малую часть входных слов в строке можно просто отсеять по длине, а не тестировать все подряд, а использование для такой конкретной задачи регулярных выражение это, как говорится, из пушки по воробьям.

```
string line = "фыв йцу ячс йцук фыва ячсм йцуке ааа ббб";
string[] words = line.Split(' ');
char[] letters = new char[] { 'а', 'о', 'у', 'э', 'ы', 'я', 'ё', 'ю', 'е', 'и' };

char s, e;
List<string> result = new List<string>();

foreach (string w in words) {
    if (w.Length != 3) continue;

    s = w[0];
    e = w[2];

    if(letters.Contains(s) &&  letters.Contains(e)){
        result.Add(w);
        Console.WriteLine(w);
    }
}
```

Comment: Использование в данной ситуации pure-кода, вместо простого регулярного выражения- как из пушки по воробьям стрелять ;)

Comment: @ReinRaus можно взять файл на несколько гигабайт и сравнить :)

Comment: в качестве доработки с регулярными выражениями, то из первой и последней буквы можно склеить строку, и проверить уже ее регуляркой.

Comment: Сравните ;-) регулярные выражения дают проблемы с производительностью только если в них есть квантификация, способная создать слишком много точек возврата. В данном регулярном выражении квантификаций вообще нет. Проверьте. Мне тоже будет интересно :)